# Backup automatizado em SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, backup

No meu atual cenário tenho um serviço do *Windows* que roda em segundo plano que em determinado horário por mim especificado, roda um *batch* que faz o *backup* do banco e salva na pasta do *dropbox*. Mas o que acontece é que nem sempre o *dropbox* tem permissão para acessar a internet devido as permissões de usuários.

Para ter uma saída eu pesquise na internet e achei esse site do [Free Sql Server Express Backup Utility](http://www.sqlbackupmaster.com/features/sqlexpressscheduledbackup), que é gratuito, e uma ferramenta paga, que é o [Sql Backup and FTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/)....

Minha pergunta é a seguinte: alguém usou esses *softwares*? São confiáveis? Existe alguma alternativa que eu possa usar?

*Só a nível de informação mesmo, eu quero usar um utilitário que faça o backup e jogue direto no meu *FTP*, pois pelo *FTP* não é preciso de permissão de usuário*.

Comment: Além [dessa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487675/how-can-i-schedule-a-daily-backup-with-sql-server-express) no SOen também.

Comment: Uma sugestão de backup: faça-o normalmente no PC e agende uma rotina para transferir o backup para o Dropbox. Essa rotina pode ser um *bat* que realiza o FTP ou mesmo um VBScript que lê os arquivos mais recentes para transferir via FTP. Te mando um exemplo se precisar.

Comment: Ja usei o *SQL Backup and FTP*  e funciona bem. Tem a limitação de duas bases de dados, mas para usos simples e o suficiente. Se quiser uma solução com código, pode sempre usar PowerShell e o modulo `sqlps` que disponibiliza um comando para fazer *backup*.

Comment: @ricarela. nesse momento não posso utilizar do dropbox cara. O usuário não é administraor e por isso barra o acesso a internet do dropbox, ou seja, o arquivo de backup não é enviado e com isso não tenho controle algum, e é isso que quero evitar nesse momento. São muitos clientes, e se por exemplo 20 não estiverem mandando eu não vou ter controle sobre isso. =(

Comment: @Omni cara, então eu acho que vou usá-lo mesmo. Não sei se o gratuito tem suporte a FTP, mas vou tentar! Valeu a dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu utilizei as duas. São ótimas ferramentas de backup automatizado do SqlServer. Mas optei por usar a [SqlBackupANdFTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/), pelo fato de ser mais fácil de mexer e ter mais recursos.

Com a compra da licença mais opções podem ser adquiridas, mas a free já atende a quase todos os casos onde se precisa de um backup automatizado.

Não há dependência do windows, então se caso o windows reiniciar, a ferramenta volta sozinha, sem interferência humana.

Answer (score 0):

Sou usuário ativo de backups, por isso insisto nesse post. Sempre trabalho com pelo menos 2 ambientes: dev e prod (também para base de dados). Só levo para produção o que está legal em dev. Mantenho backups desses ambientes e com mais cuidado para dev (por incrivel que pareça), pois é onde mais mexo. Faça backup! E não deixe em um único lugar, tão pouco no mesmo lugar onde os objetos estão sendo "backupeados". Deixe em um ou duas unidades da rede. Organize um disco externo em outra estação e faça backup nele. Arrume um micro mais antigo só para receber backups... E TESTE-OS! Faça simulações de desastre constantemente.